# Which kind of protocol apache beam uses to write and read files from cloud storage, is it HTTPS or Binary?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I wanted to know which kind of protocol apache beam uses to read and write to cloud storage. Is it HTTPS or Binary(Blob).I tried to google it but I did not find. I know gsutil command uses HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Using HTTP/HTTPS doesn't mean that the data being transferred isn't binary.

Comment: Thanks but still is not clear which kind of protocol apache beam uses to transfer files.

Comment: I'm like 99% certain it will be HTTP/HTTPS. Google aren't going to support an entirely new protocol when there's a perfectly good one already implemented, just for Apache Beam. You could test this locally and do some analysis of your network traffic. Perhaps something as simple as proxying through Telerik's Fiddler tool would be enough.

Comment: In java if you are not using apache beam , we can use Blob blob = storage.get(BUCKET_NAME, OBJECT_NAME);
ReadChannel r = blob.reader(); Apache beam uses some API to read files in large number, so if beam uses HTTPS it will not be slower than binary for reading many number of files from a bucket. I am running dataflow jobs through command directly in google cloud shell. There is  some security restriction, I can not run in local.

Comment: Isn't the `Blob` class from the GCS SDK just using HTTP internally? In C# I can use Google Storage as a `Stream`, but internally it just maps onto HTTP connections.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, but still not sure about apache beam. How we can be sure about beam.

Comment: If you really want to be sure, you could read the relevant [source code](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing 2 things: Transport layer and data encoding.

- Does Google use HTTP transport? YES, for all the API. HTTPS or gRPC (HTTP/2) are commonly use.
- Does Google use binary encoding to speed up the transfert? As said before, transport can be HTTPS or gRPC. HTTPS is commonly use for REST API, and transport JSON text format. Of course, you can exchange files in binary format (GZIP for example to compress and speed up the transfert). gRPC is a binary protocol. You don't exchange JSON, but binary representation of the data that you want to exchange. And thereby, the file transfert is also in binary mode.

Now, what use Beam? As often, the Google libraries use gRPC behind the scene, and thus, the encoding is binary. If you perform yourselves REST API call, with JSON, and HTTP will be use for that; but file content is, when it can (depends on your request accept content header), transferred in binary.

---

**EDIT 1**

For BEAM, I had a look to the source code. You have [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/c4f62ca933b570ec300f501dc02f360054d5634a/sdks/java/extensions/google-cloud-platform-core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/gcp/util/GcsUtil.java#L441), for example, the creation of `GoogleCloudStorageImpl` object.

If you have a look to this full class name: `import com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl;`. Ok, let's see the hadoop package!!

The [Javadoc is clear: JSON API is used](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.cloud.bigdataoss/gcsio/1.9.7/com/google/cloud/hadoop/gcsio/GoogleCloudStorageImpl.html). to confirm that, I went to the [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/ab3d29623c253ff2065df759978a6c14f2dd716a/gcsio/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/gcsio/GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java#L289), and YES, the JSON format is used for the API communication.

**BUT**, keep in mind that is the API communication, the metadata around the file content. The file content should be sent in binary format (plain text of b64 encoding should be strange).

Comment: Thanks but still it is just assumption that apache beam uses gRPC but not confirm. I was looking at source code but still this will take time to confirm.

Comment: Agree, it's not so easy, I update my answer with pointers